# Wrong data type while using linked tables in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL server database which needs to be linked to MS Access forms.

I have a table with one column as both Identity and is a also a primary key and is big int

But **after linking the table** , if i open the design window of table in MS access , it is `converted as text` .

Why it is converting the Identity column to Text while linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bigint is not a datatype supported by access. If you wanted the value to stay as a numeric value in access you would have to change the source column in the SQL server table to numeric(19,0).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: ..I agree with you . This should be the case . Thanks for pointing it out.